# reading columns from text file python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large .txt file more than 10000 column names. It doesn't have any feature values and has only the list of features to be added.

To clarify, the text file has  the column names in the following format:

```
Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
…
```

It only has the list of columns that needs to be imported as column names in my data frame.

I would like to read these column names straight into a dataframe. Is this possible with a pandas command e.g.
df = pd.read_XXX()

Basically   the final dataframe  needs to look

```
   final_dataframe = df['Column1'] + df['Column2'] + df['Column3'] + df['Column4'] + df['Column5']
```

...
If not with pandas, can someone advise on how to read in a file of this type? I am not familiar with this format.

What i have tried so far:
i tried something very similar to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = pd.read_csv('entire_set.txt', header=None)
```

What this gave me was an  empty dataframe with all the column names that I want. This didnt quite help.

To clarify this problem further, i have a dataframe **df_full** which has more 20k columns with the values. However i need only a subset of that dataframe. The columns that I need in my final dataframe are enlisted in  text file **entire_set.txt**

If my dataframe was small,i could read the column names from my text file and create a new dataframe using the following:

```
   final_dataframe = df_full['Column1'] + df_full['Column2'] + df_full['Column3'] + df_full['Column4'] + df_full['Column5'] ...
```

However this isnt viable for larger feature set. are there ways to only use columns in df from df_full with values.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)? It seems from your description like `pd.read_csv()` would give you the file contents as a pandas series that you could use how you like

Comment: To clarify, you want an empty dataframe, with 10000 columns and 0 rows? Or does the row data come from somewhere else?

Comment: i have added details edits to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will create an empty DataFrame where the column names were imported from a txt using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = pd.read_csv('column_names.txt', header=None)[0].values)
```

If you already have a Dataframe and you want to select only the columns in the txt file you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = old_df[pd.read_csv('column_names.txt', header=None)[0].values]

print(new_df)
```

Comment: yes i had tried this but what it gave me was an empty dataframe with the column names. I do have a dataframe DF_full which has 20k + columns and this helped me created an empty dataframe with the required columns. Is there a way I could create a new dataframe with only the columns mentioned in df along with values from df_full. What i was doing so far was final_dataframe = df_full['Column1'] + df_full['Column2'] + df_full'Column3'] + df_full['Column4'] + df_full['Column5'] .. Is there an easier way to do this  as this insnt viable for 10000 column names

Comment: I added a new script to my answer. See if it is what you want